# Is flatness condition for proper base change actually needed?

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

In his 1988 Paper on Resolutions of Unbounded Complexes, Spaltenstein proves that $Lg^*Rf_! \cong RF_! LG^*$ where 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>F>> B\\
    @V G V V @VV g V\\
    C @>>f> D
\end{CD}
is a cartesian square of ringed spaces. He requires an additional finiteness condition for the fibres of $f$, and (and this is my question) that $g$ is flat.

Since $g$ is flat so is $G$, and there is no actual left derived functor. Is there a known example showing that the statement is false without the flatness assumption? Are there newer sources than stuff from the 80s?

Comment: The book "Categories and Sheaves" by Kashiwara and Schapira contains quite a bit on the unbounded derived category, but as far as I remember they do not treat any base change formulas. For more there might be something on the Stacks project.